# Android scrollview does not work on dynamic content

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am dynamic creating table rows and textviews from my JSON data which I get from an api. Currently the data gets displayed correctly, but somehow my scrollview does not work. It does not scroll. I did add a ScrollView but I guess I am doing something wrong there.

My Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tlMarksTable"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            </TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the part in which I generate the views looks like this:

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
setContentView(tableRow);
tableRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

for(int i= 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String id         = jsonobject.getString("id");
    String content    = jsonobject.getString("content");

    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(content);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        textView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
    } else {
        textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.boldText);
    }
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.highlightedTextViewColor);
    textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.joke_content_font_size));
    tableRow.addView(textView);
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just use a gridview?

Comment: @tyczj Sorry I do not have much experience in this, could you explain further what you mean?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

have your inner component configured like this:

```
          <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tlMarksTable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            </TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

by the way the outer `RelativeLayout` ViewGroup doesn't do much

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I removed the outer `RelativeLayout` and replaced the the xml with your provided one but I still can not scroll any other ideas left?

Comment: is ScrollView your top ViewGroup?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem i see here, is that the `LinearLayout` that encapsulates your `TableLayout`, has `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. This means that the inner child of the `ScrollView`, will have the same height that the parent, resulting in a non-scrolling layout.

Why don't you try removing that `LinearLayout`, and leaving the `TableLayout` as the only child? Remember to set the height of that child to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

By the way, i suggest using a `ListView` for displaying large amounts of data.

One last thing: there is no need of declaring the xml namespace (`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`) in each Layout declaration. Only with one declaration at the root element will be fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a recyclerview?
You should use retrofit to consume WS

Comment: What do you mean with WS?

Comment: Web Service, data from API